# Could not find or load main class view.PokerGame

Tags: java, javafx, error-handling

The compilation works perfectly, but when I try to run it it gives me the error message of not being able to find or load the main class.

I compiled my code using:

```
javac src/main/java/model/*.java src/main/java/viewcontroller/*.java src/main/java/view/*.java
```

And then ran it using:

```
java -cp src/main/java view.PokerGame
```

My TA's for my CS class said this is the way that it needs to be compiled and ran, but it is not working for some reason.

Comment: Did you try to run `java -cp src/main/java PokerGame`?

Comment: What package declarations do you have in the PokerGame.java file

Comment: If you do `ls src/main/java/view` do you see `PokerGame.class`?

Comment: I tried running it that way Vasiliy, and it still gave the same error.

Comment: The only package declaration in the class is package main.java.view

Comment: Yes, I see PokerGame.class when I do ls

Comment: The package should be just `view`: you are asking it to execute `view.PokerGame`.

Comment: You should use maven or gradle for creating some executable jar-file ;) or some IDE which has integrated support for JavaFX